# Example for point addition using Jacobi transformation and small integers

Tags: elliptic-curves

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3zzNa42-tQ) explanation is great because it shows an example using small numbers, if it wasn't for that example my code would be wrong.

Still: the code takes 0.5 seconds to calculate 300 point doublings using 256 bit numbers. I found it's faster to do point addition or doubling using the Jacobi transformation or Weierstrass transformation but I can't find explanation examples using small numbers.

Can someone write an example of point addition using Jacobi transformation?

Comment: Just a hint: you can take a look at the [Explicit-Formulas Database](http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/). There's plenty of formulas for different form of elliptic curves. You can find point additions detailed as a succession of elementary operations (multiplication, squaring, addition over the base field).

Comment: I would really like an example using small numbers because learning from the equations alone would have made me calculate division incorrectly, substraction too. I predict similar mistakes will happen if I do the jacobi transformation